# Optimizer got an empty parameter list in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I try to use convolutional network structures in a VAE experiment, the code is something like:

```
Class CNN(nn.Module):...

hparams1=[...]
hparams2=[...]

Model1=CNN(hyparams1)
Model2=CNN(hyparams2)

def VAE(x):
   encoder=Model1(x)
   z=reparameterize(encoder)  #reparameterize is defined
   decoder=Model2(z)
   return decoder

if args.cuda:
    Model1.cuda()
    Model2.cuda()

parameters = chain(Model1.parameters(), Model2.parameters())
optimizer = optim.Adam(parameters, lr=1e-3)

Error:Optimizer got an empty parameter list.
```

The same problem occurs when I defind VAE as a class:

```
class VAE(nn.Module):
  def encoder(x,model):
     return model(x)

  def reparameterize():

  def decoder(z,model):
     return model(z)

  def forward(x,Model1,Model2)
     output=encoder(x,Model1)
     z=reparameterize(output)
     return decoder(z,Model2)

model=VAE()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

Error:Optimizer got an empty parameter list.
```

I guess maybe the problem is that I fail to initialize the parameters in a class VAE, but I don't know how to deal with it. Thank you very much!

Comment: The first parameter of `forward` should be `self`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you can use:

```
parameters = list(Model1.parameters())+ list(Model2.parameters())
optimizer = optim.Adam(parameters, lr=1e-3)
```

In the second case, you didn't create the object, so basically you can try this:

```
model = VAE()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
```

By the way, you can start from modifying the [VAE example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/vae) provided by Pytorch.

**EDIT**

Perhaps you miss the initial function or initialize the model in a wrong way. See the [init](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/vae/main.py#L41) function here.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In the second case, I have created the object but omitted it above. However, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

I have got the answer.

```
Class CNN(nn.Module):...

hparams1=[...]
hparams2=[...]

class VAE(nn.Module):

    self.Model1=CNN(hyparams1)
    self.Model2=CNN(hyparams2)

  def encoder(x,model):
     return model(x)

  def reparameterize():

  def decoder(z,model):
     return model(z)

  def forward(x)
     output=encoder(x,self.Model1)
     z=reparameterize(output)
     return decoder(z,self.Model2)

model=VAE()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
```

Comment: please explain the difference